Is there a way to suppress 'resolve' messages sent to pager duty
Our pager duty is integrated to alert manager, and we want to stop an specific alert from auto resolving. To my knowledge, the best way to do that would be changing the alert manager configuration so it doesn't send the resolve message ... unfortunately we currently don't have permissions to do so.
Is it possible to just set pager duty to ignore the 'resolve' messages through a basic rule?
I can make a basic rule to ignore messages that contain "resolved", but I can't find anywhere if that would work.
